# Basic Scala hashmap - return types are ignored

Tags: scala, types, hashmap

I'm trying out Scala, in particular the Hashmap - I've tried something along these lines (both with and without explicitly specifying types):

```
scala> var x = HashMap("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
x: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)
scala> x.get("a")
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> x.get("a") + x.get("b")
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Int]
 required: String
       x.get("a") + x.get("b")
```

Oddly enough, even though the Int is correctly inferred, I'm unable retain these as `Int` - so for instance, I cant sum them following the `get`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the return type of the `get` method. It returns `Option[Int]`, not `Int`:

```
def get (key: A): Option[B]
```

An `Option[Int]` can either be a `Some` containing an integer, or a `None` (which you'd get if the key wasn't present in the map).

If you just want an `Int`, and possibly have a `NoSuchElementException` thrown if the given key doesn't exist in the map, just use the `apply` method, or its shorter syntactic sugar:

```
x("a") + x("b")
```

Or, if you want to add the values *inside* the `Option[Int]`s, returning another `Option[Int]`:

```
for (a <- x.get("a"); b <- x.get("b")) yield a + b
```

This will get you a `Some` if both keys are present, and a `None` if one or both are missing.

Alternatively, if you don't care about missing keys and want to use a default value when a key is missing, use `getOrElse`:

```
x.getOrElse("a", 0) + x.getOrElse("b", 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Notice that `.get("a")` returns `Option[Int]`.  You can't add `Option[Int]` even explicitly.  I suspect the `String` part is a red herring due to some implicit option conversion that's in scope.  You can add them if you unwrap them from `Option`:

```
scala> var y = x.get("a").get + x.get("b").get
y: Int = 3
```

Comment: Note that x.get("a").get is equivalent to x("a"), both with fail with a NoSuchElementException if "a" is not a valid key in the map.